# If $G = H$ is a non-trivial group, is it possible for $G*H$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-product

If $G = H$ is a non-trivial group, is it possible for $G*H$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$

Comment: What is $G*H$? Do you mean $G\times H$?

Comment: @ajotatxe it's a free product, most likely, as indicated by the tag.

Comment: Then $G=H=\Bbb Z$ should work. And I don't know if this has much to do with general topology...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The free group $Z*Z$ is isomorphic to which group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384562/the-free-group-zz-is-isomorphic-to-which-group)

Comment: The non-trivial free product is never commutative.

Comment: @ajotatxe No, $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the free group of rank $2$, not to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Answer (score 5):

A non trivial free product is never commutative.

You could argue using reduced words and stuff but it would soon be tedious. Here's a proof using only the universal property : let $X = G\sqcup H$ modded out (as a set) by $e_G = e_H$, and have $G,H$ act on it in the following way : $G$ acts on the copy of itself, and acts trivially on $H\setminus \{e\}$, and symmetrically for $H$.

Then we get maps $f, k : G,H \to \mathfrak S X$, so by the universal property $G*H\to \mathfrak SX$.

It's easy to check that if $g\in G\setminus \{e\}, h\in H\setminus \{e\}$, $f(g)$ and $k(h)$ don't commute, e.g. you may look at how $f(g)k(h)$ and $k(h)f(g)$ act on $e$.

Comment: Another way to describe this set $X$ (in case the OP likes it better) is as the set of $(g,h)$ in $G\times H$ such that $g=e$ or $h=e$ (or both).  (These are the two standard ways to describe the [wedge sum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wedge+sum) of two pointed sets.)

Comment: Interesting proof! Curious about the the image of the homomorphism in $\mathfrak{S}X$. This is a group $K$ naturally mapping onto $G\times H$, and the kernel consists of (all?) even finitely supported permutations of $X$. (Remark: for any nontrivial $g\in G,h\in H$, $[g,h]$ acts as a $3$-cycle.)