# Finite groups acting on torus

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology

Consider the 2-dimensional torus $T^2$ and let $G$ be a finite group acting (faithfully) by diffeomorphisms of $T^2$. Is there a bound for the number of generators of $G$? For example, can it be 5-generated?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would be of some help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell%E2%80%93Weil_theorem

Comment: Also this answer implies https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789462/the-commutator-subgroup-of-modular-group-is-a-free-group-of-rank-2 existence of free subgroup and thus subgoups with an arbitrary number of generators

Comment: @GregoryG: I'm not sure what context you intended your second comment to apply to, but in the context of this question there is certainly no free group of rank $\ge 2$ in sight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is indeed a bounded number of generators, and it follows from an explicit description of all possible such groups $G$. The idea is that you can make $G$ act by isometries with respect to a Euclidean metric on $T^2$, and then you can lift $G$ via a universal covering map $f : \mathbb R^2 \to T^2$ to obtain a Euclidean crystallographic group $\widetilde G$. These groups are known up to isomorphism: they are [the 17 wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group). Since this is just a finite set of finitely generated groups, one obtains a bound for the number of generators of $\widetilde G$, and since $G$ is just a quotient group of $\widetilde G$ one obtains the same bound for the number of generators of $G$. If you walk through the list of 17, you'll see that each is generated by at most 4 elements.

Notice one thing that this proof does not say: there are not finitely many isomorphism types of the groups $G$, because the kernel of the quotient homomorphism $\widetilde G \mapsto G$ can have arbitrarily large index. What makes this proof work is that the infinite set of possible $G$'s is just a set of quotients of the finite set of groups $\widetilde G$.

Comment: How can you make the $G$ act by isometries with respect to a Euclidean metric on $T^2$?  (I understand that you can make $G$ act by isometries with respect to some Riemannian metric, but why would this metric necessarily be Euclidean?)

Comment: Starting with a given $G$-invariant Riemannian metric, apply the [Uniformization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) to obtain the unique Riemannian metric of constant curvature in the same conformal class as the given $G$-invariant metric. By the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, that metric must have curvature zero, i.e. it must be Euclidean. By uniqueness, that metric is also $G$-invariant.

Comment: Oh, duh!  I forgot how nice surfaces are!  Thanks!