# topological action on torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p$ be a prime. Suppose $\Bbb Z_p$ (generated by $g$) acts on $S^1\times S^1$, i.e., corresponding to $g$, we have a map $g^*: S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times S^1$, which is diffeomorphism as well as group homomorphism also. We can think of $S^1\times S^1$ as $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$.

My question is does there exist a linear map $\tilde g^*: \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ which gives rise to the map $g^*$ by passing to the quotient?

Comment: Are you missing conditions on your action?  Every linear action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ fixes the origin, but there are $\mathbb{Z}_p$ actions on a torus which have no fixed points, e.g., the action rotating one of the factors by $2\pi/p$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I am considering Lie group action and I have edited the question. Could you please tell whether is it true now? Thank you.

Comment: @mathstudent: Your edit did not clarify anything. When you say "linear" do you mean "affine"? Also, for a finite Lie group, such as $Z_p$, saying a "Lie group action" only means "action by diffeomorphisms." Lastly, do you mean to ask: "Given an order $p$ diffeomorphism of the torus $g:T^2\to T^2$, does there exist a covering map $R^2\to T^2$ with respect to which $g$ lifts to an affine map $\tilde{g}: T^2\to T^2$?" This is true but is rather nontrivial. You also do not need prime order for this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472805/finite-groups-acting-on-torus

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have edited my question. I'm sorry. I assume $\Bbb Z_p$ is acting by automorphism of $S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: This still makes no sense: The word "automorphism" has no meaning unless you specify the structure. When one writes $S^1$, it can mean a smooth manifold (and, thus, "an automorphism" means "a diffeomorphism") or a Lie group (in which case,  "an automorphism" means "an automorphism of the Lie group"). Or it can mean some completely different structure (complex, Riemannian,....). It can also be that you are taking $S^1$ to be an abstract group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm sorry for creating such confusion. I have edited. Thank you for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can say more: Consider the Lie group $G=S^1\times ... \times S^1$ and let $f: G\to G$ be a Lie group automorphism. Then $f$ lifts to an automorphism $\tilde{f}$ of the universal covering group $\tilde{G}={\mathbb R}^n$. Each automorphism of a Lie group $G$ induces an automorphism of the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ by differentiation at the identity element. But for the commutative Lie group  $\tilde{G}={\mathbb R}^n$, the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ is canonically identified with ${\mathbb R}^n$ so that the exponential map $\exp: \tilde{G}\to {\mathfrak g}$ is the identity map. Now, as a Lie algebra, ${\mathfrak g}$ is just the vector space ${\mathbb R}^n$, hence, its automorphisms are general linear transformations. Hence, in our case, $\tilde{f}$ is a linear transformation.

See more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence#Homomorphisms) on the Lie group-Lie algebra correspondence.